# Nuxt Content Security Policy Safari refused to execute script

Tags: safari, nuxt.js, content-security-policy

Try to update Content-security-policy already in place in nuxt.config.js.

The only problem is with Safari 12.1 with this error code :
"Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy."

The actual policy for scripts working fine on Chrome / Firefox / Edge.

```
script-src 'sha256-4/dvfTuLo2+K9SC3WDjj11xaktBdWBmmiQ0bPeQn+Cc=' 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://scriptscource1.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com https://scriptscource2.com https://scriptscource3.com
```

Hash seem to be provide automatically by Nuxt

nuxt.conf.js on Nuxt V 2.5.1

```
    render: {
        csp: {
            hashAlgorithm: 'sha256',
            policies: {
                "script-src": [
                    "'unsafe-inline'",
                    "https://scriptscource1.com/",
                    "https://scriptscource2.com",
                    "https://scriptscource3.com/"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I have find this issue on github : https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4876
But i don't find a way to fix or understand my problem.